# Explain this ColorBox code in detail

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to learn the real nitty gritty details of Javascript, so I would appreciate it if someone could explain this code for me.  In ColorBox, the author defines his public method as so:

```
publicMethod = $.fn[colorbox] = $[colorbox] = function (options, callback) {
    // do stuff...
};
```

Other public methods are then defined such as:

```
publicMethod.remove = function () {
    // do more stuff
};
```

In practice, I know that these function can then be called as *$.colorbox()* and *$.colorbox.remove()*, but I'm a little confused by the actual syntax.  Specifically, what is happening when he assigns **"$.fn[colorbox]"** and **"$[colorbox]"** to publicMethod?

Do you have any commentary on this code?  Is this a good design pattern?  Are there other patterns you would recommend?

Comment: Wouldn't that first block of code be a multiple assignment of the anonymous function to publicMethod, $.fn[colorbox], and $[colorbox]?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right.  But, what exactly happens when you assign that anon function to $.fn[colorbox] and $[colorbox].  I guess I don't understand the brackets notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript each object is an associative array at the same time, object properties are also array keys. This means that `obj.prop = 1` and `obj["prop"] = 1` are exactly the same thing. Also, methods are simply properties that have a function as their value. So `$["colorbox"] = function() {...}` creates an anonymous function and assigns it as property `colorbox` of the object `$` (`$` is a regular variable name in JavaScript), this function becomes method `$.colorbox()` then. Note that I used the string `"colorbox"`, your code example has it without quotation marks however - which would interpreted as a variable name, so a variable `colorbox` with the value `"colorbox"` is probably used there.

Functions are objects as well so you can set custom properties on them. In the example the property `remove` is being set on the function object and becomes its method.

Comment: Yes, I can see above that he declared

colorbox = 'colorbox'

Comment: `obj.prop = 1` and `obj["prop"] = 1` are exactly the same thing. Perfect explaination

Answer (score 1):

According to the Mozilla javascript guide, the square brackets are used as property accessors, in this case.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1):

Colorbox author here and I wanted to say Wladimir is exactly right.  I used the bracket notation so that the variable (colorbox) could be shortened when ran through a minifier, as the same string was used repeatedly in the source.

In JavaScript, objects (in this case, the function expression) are passed around through reference.

So $.colorbox, $.fn.colorbox, and publicMethod all point to the same object.  When a new property is added to publicMethod (ie publicMethod.remove = function(){};), $.fn.colorbox also receive the property as both reference the same object.

$.fn.pluginName is the convention for jQuery plugins, and $.colorbox is just an alias for that.  publicMethod was a shorthand for $.fn.colorbox used within the plugin that would be shortened when the script was passed through a minifier.